# How to store images and .mp3 file locally from API flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have displayed images and played audio from GET request. Now I need to store the images and .mp3 audio files locally. Is there any way to achieve this. I need to store List of images and audio files. Thank You.
This is the way I get response from API.

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1052,
            "title": "1",
            "audio_file": "",
            "desc": null,
            "display_title": 1,
            "audio_src": null,
            "image_src": "https://topik.com/storage/uploads/topik/images/20220620092536.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 1053,
            "title": "2",
            "audio_file": "",
            "desc": null,
            "display_title": 1,
            "audio_src": null,
            "image_src": "https://topik.com/storage/uploads/topik/images/20220620092545.jpg"
        },
]
```

Comment: Does API give a response as files? Can you give a sample API URL String?

Comment: I added the API response above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path) and [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to implement this. Sample code for the Api response you shared:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

/// Returns the response from the api in a Map
Map getResponseMap(String apiUrl) {
    var response = http.get(apiUrl);
    Map responseMap = jsonDecode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return responseMap;
}

/// Returns the list of files from the api response.
List<Map> getItemsListFromResponseMap(Map responseMap) {
    var list = responseMap['data'];
    return list.cast<Map>(); // cast the list to a list of Maps.
}

/// Returns the file name with extension.
String getFileNameFromUrl(String url) {
    String fileName = url.split('/').toList().last;
    return fileName;
}

Future<void> downloadAudioFromAPIResponse(Map singleResponseItem) async {
    String audioUrl = singleResponseItem['audio_src'];
    await saveNetworkFileToLocalDirectory(audioUrl); // Your file will be saved to the specified directoty in the [saveNetworkFileToLocalDirectory] function below.
}

Future<void> downloadImageFromAPIResponse(Map singleResponseItem) async {
    String imgUrl = singleResponseItem['image_src'];
    await saveNetworkFileToLocalDirectory(imgUrl); // Your file will be saved to the specified directoty in the [saveNetworkFileToLocalDirectory] function below.
}

Future<void> saveNetworkFileToLocalDirectory(String fileSrcUrl) async {
    var response = await http.get(fileSrcUrl);
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String filePath = join(documentDirectory.path, getFileNameFromUrl(fileSrcUrl));
    File file = new File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    // The file has been written at the filePath specified, in this case,
    // The app's document directory.
}
```

You can change the path to which the file is written by changing the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` to something else. For available paths, check out [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).

You can use the sample code to download all the files in your response as:

```
Map mainResponse = getResponseMap("YourApiRequestUrlHere");
// Get list of all item in the response by API.
List<Map> individualItems = getItemsListFromResponseMap(mainResponse);
// pre-evalute the count to improve performance by not having to call .length every time the loop finishes execution.
int count = individualItems.length; 
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Map item = individualItems[i]; // get a single item.
    if(item['audio_src'] != null && item['image_src'] != null) {
        await downloadAudioFromAPIResponse(item);
        await downloadImageFromAPIResponse(item);
    } else if (item['audio_src'] != null) {
        await downloadAudioFromAPIResponse(item);
    } else if (item['image_src'] != null) {
        await downloadImageFromAPIResponse(item);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

If my answer was helpful, please mark my answer as Correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After converting json object to dart object

use

[Internet_file](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_file) package

```
Uint8List bytes = await InternetFile.get(
      data.image_src,
      headers: headers, /* in case you want to set auth otherwise remove it*/
      process: (percentage) {
        

        print('downloadPercentage: $percentage');
      },
    );
```

Now use [PathProvider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    print("temp path : " + tempDir.toString());
    await writeToFile(bytes, '${tempPath}/filename.png');
    print("written");
```

Comment: I can save my mp3 audio files too this way??